# Google Mock std::shared_prt Invoke Problems

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googletest, googlemock

I am working with google mock to mock out the behavior of a class. The object I am mocking is a std:shared_prt. Somehow I can't redirect the method-call (of a mock method) to another method within the class.

The method I want to call redirectToStartOfBaseClass(), invokes the start()-Method of the base class (NMEADataControler)

The Mock Class:

```
class NMEADataControler_Mock : public NMEADataControler{
   ...
   //    The method I want to redirecto to ...
   void redirectToStartOfBaseClass();
   ...
   // ... when this mock method is called
   MOCK_METHOD0(start, void());
   ...
}
```

The class with the test-fixture I am using

```
class TestFixtureClass : public ::testing::Test{
   ...
   std::shared_ptr<NMEADataControler_Mock> NEMADummy;
   ...
}
```

Test Method:

```
TEST_F(TestFixtureClass, StupidTest){
   ...
   ON_CALL(*NMEADummy, start())
      .WillByDefault(Invoke( ?????? ) //What parameters to I have to put in here? 
   //To redirect to *NMEADummy->redirectToStartOfBaseClass()

}
```

I am not that experienced with C++ and quite new to it, so please forgive me if my mistakes are obvious and super stupid.

P.s: I searched for a solution for quite some time now and i can't find anything. That why I am asking you guys, I am quite desperate, I hope you can help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you just need to pass the NMEADataControler_Mock instance to Invoke, like this:

```
ON_CALL(*NMEADummy, start())
      .WillByDefault(Invoke( NMEADummy.get(), &NMEADataControler_Mock::redirectToStartOfBaseClass));
```

Here, [NMEADummy.get()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get) returns a naked pointer to your dummy.

As an aside: I don't know your use case, so maybe a `shared_ptr` is a good call in your specific instance, but it doesn't seem like it. I advise you to use `shared_ptr` only in cases where you need multiple owners of a single resource. If the Fixture is going to be the only owner of your mock, I advise you to use a `unique_ptr`. `shared_ptr` are more complex to reason about, they can introduce hard to track ref count loops (they are not garbage collected, there is no mark and sweep happening) and are more heavy-weight, because of additional storage allocated for a control block. They are also slower, because of the atomic operations used to control their refcounts.

Comment: Thank you so much divinas this helped me a lot! Now i can finally proceed development.